# Error on accessing a public static method

Tags: c#, .net

I've a .Net dll referenced in my application.
On accessing one of its method called XYZ in my C# code, I get an error:

> Attempt by method 'MyClass.ABC()' to access method 'OtherClass.XYZ()' failed.

When I see the metadata in VS.Net, I see  that it shows this method XYZ as public static only.
What could I be missing here please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the call for public static method

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to access the method, and if possible the method you are calling?

Comment: Please prove some code to check.

Also check if you have the namespace in using or not. Also check if the function is called only by using the class name.

Comment: Please go through the link below, Then you will have a better understanding on static methods > [C# Static Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-method)

Comment: sorry, for not mentioning that am using class name when calling the method.Have updated my question.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it using the class name. For example

```
public static class MyClass
{
  public static void MyMethod()
  { // Do something
  }
}
```

When calling you need to use

```
MyClass.MyMethod();
```

Comment: In other word, you need to use the type to access static method and use an object instance to access dynamic methods.

Comment: Try to check the access modifiers. Are you sure your class and method are in the scope?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - this is what happened in my case:

1. I have an assembly my.dll which defines  `internal static void Foo();`
2. my.dll defines `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("unittests")]`
3. I have a test assembly unittests.dll which calls Foo().
4. I have test.localtestsettings with deploys my.dll and unittests.dll.

Through some mumbo jumbo, the testsettings file was deploying a stale version of a.dll which didn't have the AttributeInternalsVisibleTo.

This put me in a position where the code passed the compile-time check but threw a MethodAccessException at run-time. The cause in my case was an internal method being invoked from an assembly for which it should not have been visible. This is a type of security exception which I did not enjoy debugging. Good luck.